# Como verificar com javascript/jquery qual(is) objeto(s) está(ão) provocando uma barra de rolagem na página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Gostaria de montar um script de verificação, pois muitas vezes é dificílimo encontrar o por que da página estar com barra de rolagem, principalmente quando usamos algum framework responsivo que possui muito código css e muito código js manipulando.

Preciso de dicas para montar uma lógica que me apontasse os objetos que estão fazendo com que a barra de rolagem apareça. Não tenho a mínima idéia de como começar. De repente podemos juntos construir algo que possa ser útil a todos, ou se alguém já tiver um pronto melhor ainda.

Meu código de teste está como resposta para caso alguem queira melhorar.

Comment: Uma maneira que deve funcionar (sem pensar em eficiência) é verificar a posição e altura de todos os elementos da página, e ver se algum deles ultrapassa a altura da janela.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua pergunta é muito interessante, eis a minha solução:

```
function escanearPagina(el) {
    var i = [],
    t, x, y, w, h,
    ww = $(window).width(),
    wh = $(window).height();

    el.each(function(){
        t = $(this);
        x = t[0].offsetLeft;
        y = t[0].offsetTop;
        w = t.outerWidth();
        h = t.outerHeight();

        if (w > ww || +x + w > ww || h > wh || +y + h > wh) {
            i.push(t[0]);
        }
    });
    return i;
}
```

**Vantagens:**

- Permite que você defina qual área da página você quer que ele escaneie;
- Calcula também baseado em padding, e não só na width dos elementos (`box-sizing:border-box` não afeta o script);
- Retorna um array com os elementos encontrados;

**Como usar:**

```
var resultado = escanearPagina($('body *')); //retorna todos os elementos dentro do body que geram scroll
$(resultado).addClass('eu-quebro-o-layout');
```

#### Segue exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/xE78N/4/)

Comment: Bem legal a sua solução, vai além da questão do tamanho de um único objeto. Vou tentar utilizá-lo.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo eu dei uma atualizada no código e no exemplo, fiz umas melhorias, caso você já tenha pego o código só atualiza pelo novo daqui :)

Comment: Eu acrescentaria no if `x < 0 || y < 0`

Comment: @LeandroAmorim então, eu não adicionei verificação para ```x``` e ```y``` negativos porque eles não geram scroll na janela. Como a pergunta foi só sobre os elementos que geram scroll na página, preferi não "escanear" estes elementos. Apesar de achar que dependendo do caso seria interessante implementar essa verificação também. :)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode testar com essa função:

```
function isOverflowed(element){
    return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight || element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth;
}
```

Comment: Parecia bem interessante. Mas simulei com uma div q excedia a largura da pagina e retornou false.

Comment: A função está correta, você deve passar o elemento HTML. Caso esteja usando o jQuery ou algum outro, extrai-a o elemento. Por exemplo, dá para usar aqui no próprio StackOverflow, abrindo seu console, inserindo a função e depois mandando os comandos: isOverflowed($(".vote-count-post").get(0)) ou isOverflowed($(".post-text").get(0))

Comment: Eu testei assim: $('div').each(function(){
                    alert(isOverflowed($(this)));
                }); esta errado?

Comment: Sim, quando você puxa o $("div") você tem um objeto jQuery ao invés de um objeto do DOM. Logo: $(".post-text").clientHeight = undefined e $(".post-text").get(0).clientHeight = 268.

Answer (score 1):

Implementei um script para fazer isso usando jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var $w = $(window),
        wb = $w.height(),
        wr = $w.width(),
        arr = [];

    $('*').each(function () {

        var $this = $(this),
            ofs = $this.offset(),
            eb = ofs.top + $this.height(),
            er = ofs.left + $this.width();

        if (eb > wb || er > wr) {
            arr.push(this);
        }

    });

    var msg = "Array contains: " + arr.length + "\n";
    for (var it = 0; it < arr.length; it++) {
        msg += arr[it].tagName + " - ";
        msg += "Largura: " + $(arr[it]).css('width') + "; ";
        msg += "Altura: " + $(arr[it]).css('height') + "; ";
        msg += "\n";
    }

    alert(msg);
});
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pKu9/1/)

Comment: Testei aqui trocando o '*' por 'div' no meu html em branco que só contem uma div com 1500 de largura mais 250 de padding em cada lado. O meu documento possui 1440 de largura. Apareceu um alert assim: Array contains: 0

Comment: É porque eu só testei a altura. =D Vou editar pra considerar também a largura!

Answer (score 0):

Estou postando aqui o meu código de teste e gostaria de ajuda para melhorá-lo. Podem editar.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    debugger;
    var docWidth = toInt($("html").css('width'));
    var docHeight = toInt($("html").css('height'));
    $('div').each(function(){
        var objWidth  = toInt($(this).css("width")) + toInt($(this).css("padding-left")) + toInt($(this).css("padding-right"));                    
        var objHeight = toInt($(this).css("height")) + toInt($(this).css("padding-top")) + toInt($(this).css("padding-bottom"));
        if ( objWidth > docWidth ){
            alert("Tamanho do objeto " + $(this).tagName + " excedeu a página: " + objWidth);
        }

        if ( objHeight > docHeight ){
            alert("Tamanho do objeto " + $(this).tagName + "excedeu a página: " + objHeight);
        }
    }); 
   function toInt(str){
        return parseInt(str.replace(/[^\d]+/g,''));
   }   
});
```

A principio ele está verificando corretamente. Mas o tagName está sempre vindo undefined (setei 'div' por enquanto para teste, mas deverá ser '*'). Depois testarei em várias situações pra ver se realmente está captando tudo da maneira certa. Acho também que faltou eu implementar o margin.